# How do I choose an specific file of my file Array List?

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, directory

I made a function that I call with a code similar to this:

```
String[] listado= formacion.list();
for (int i; i<listado.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Los archivos de la carpeta"+rutaCarpeta+"son "+listado[0]
}
```

With something similar to this, my array make a numbered list of the files that I have on a specific location, okay. Thing is, I would like to ask the user to select exactly a file (and its content) in order to see it thoroughly (I hope I'm making myself clear...) and I don't know why. For instance, if the array shows me these 3 files:

1. book file
2. food file
3. nature file

I would like the console to read what I type (for example if I choose 3, and it shows me specifically file number 3 and its content). I'm pretty newbie and I don't have a clue at all, even though I looked it up... I don't properly understand how to do it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting user input from console:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = scanner.nextInt();
```

This assumes that the user only types a number.

It's also up to you to show the user which number to input. And maybe to change that number to the correct index in your list of files (since usually people count starting from 1 but java arrays start at index 0).

*Edit* Here's a quick example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] files = new String[]{"book", "food", "nature"};

    System.out.println("These files are available:");
    for(int i = 0; i<files.length;i++){
        System.out.println((i+1) + ") " + files[i]);
    }
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which file do you want to open?");
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You have chosen: " + files[input-1]);
}
```